# Get array from value inside of it

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently working on a project in PHP which will be using an API to get information about my customers. The API returns the information in JSON which I then convert into an array. The data consists of a big array with smaller arrays inside of it. Each smaller array holds information for every specific customer.

Now. How would I as efficiently as possible get one of the smaller arrays from the big array using a value inside of one of the smaller arrays? In this example, I have the **user_id** which I need to find which array it's in. Is there any function to find the array or do I need to loop through everything until I find it?

There may be up to 1000 of the smaller arrays and therefore I'm concerned if it's a good idea to loop through all of those values.

The JSON:

```
{
"purchases": [
        {
            "user_id": "Remvoed",
            "user_name": "Remvoed",
            "purchase_time": "Remvoed",
            "purchase_revoked": "Remvoed",
            "transaction_id": "Remvoed",
            "price": "Remvoed",
            "is_banned": "Remvoed",
            "ban_endtime": "Remvoed"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "Remvoed",
            "user_name": "Remvoed",
            "purchase_time": "Remvoed",
            "purchase_revoked": "Remvoed",
            "transaction_id": "Remvoed",
            "price": "Remvoed",
            "is_banned": "Remvoed",
            "ban_endtime": "Remvoed"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "Remvoed",
            "user_name": "Remvoed",
            "purchase_time": "Remvoed",
            "purchase_revoked": "Remvoed",
            "transaction_id": "Remvoed",
            "price": "Remvoed",
            "is_banned": "Remvoed",
            "ban_endtime": "Remvoed"
        },
    ]
}
```

Thanks!

Kind regards, Jonathan.

Comment: Does the API you use allow you to filter results, say using a specific user id?

Comment: All user_id are _Remvoed_ which one do you want?

Comment: @WilliamPerron I'm not sure if I can filter them. The documentation is not very good. Right now the post request looks like this: https://www.gmodstore.com/api/scripts/purchases/SCRIPT_ID?api_key=MYAPIKEY

Comment: @AbraCadaver I was assuming the data was obfuscated for the purpose of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `user_id`s are unique, then decode the JSON to an array, extract to an array indexed by `user_id` and get that index.  Assumes that you have the `user_id` stored in `$userid`:

```
$result = array_column(json_decode($json, true)['purchases'], null, 'user_id')[$userid];
```

If you'll need to do this more than once in the execution, then:

```
$ids = array_column(json_decode($json, true)['purchases'], null, 'user_id');
$one = $ids[$userid];
$new = $ids[$newid];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find multiple purchases that match your user_id, you're going to have to iterate the whole `purchases` array regardless. You can use `array_filter` if you like.

```
$user_purchases = array_filter($data->purchases, function($purchase) use ($user_id) {
    return $purchase->user_id == $user_id;
});
```

But if user_id is unique in that set, or if you just need to find one purchase for a user, you *should* use a loop, because you can break out of it as soon as you find a match. If you use one of the `array_` functions, you won't have that level of control, and it's going to go through the whole thing.

```
$user_purchase = null;
foreach ($data->purchases as $purchase) {
    if ($purchase->user_id == $user_id) {
        $user_purchase = $purchase;
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($user_purchase);
```